# Installing ArcGIS 10.1 on SQL Server 2008 R2 Cluster

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, performance

We're running into some performance issues when accessing large enterprise geodatabases on a SQL Server 2008 R2 cluster.  The database itself performs well and returns queries fine but presenting the information back to ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 is prohibitively slow.

Connection is direct connect.
Data type in SDE is DBO.
Machines are VMs with 16Gb RAM.

Are there any tips or tricks or known documents for installs of these on SQL Server clusters where a node instance is presented?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Perhaps you can edit your question (just click edit above) to add details of the type of queries that are causing problems, and some metrics of what is "prohibitively slow"?

Comment: Just to clarify - you're talking about using SDE to store spatial data in SQL server? Or are you using the SQL server native spatial data type?

Answer (score 2):

See this article: "A common question that I see in Desktop Support is “Why is ArcMap performing so slowly?”"

> http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2012/06/07/troubleshooting-slow-performance-in-arcgis-desktop/

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem before and found using [PerfQAnalyzer for ArcGIS](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2012/04/03/new-arcgis-performance-calibration-tool/) to be very useful to analyze drawing and fetch speeds in the map.

Answer (score 2):

Outside of the maps I found the [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) helpful in getting a grip on what/where the problem was occurring.

Sorry have to keep re-posting as I am only allowed one link per post.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you are working with ArcSDE Personal, Workgroup, or Enterprise level, your license level may cause  limitations.

Take a look [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n00000007000000) and see if you are extended beyond your license level.

Answer (score 2):

This may apply to you (It fixed this same problem for us):

[FIX: Performance might be slow when you run a parallel query against a table that has a large amount of spatial data in SQL Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2570501)

PS - We just discovered the same problem is back in SQL Server 2012.